# Use clause WHERE on calculated column (including subquery)

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

I'm unable to write condition on calculated column. I've read a several post on Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, I can't still figure that out. I have following MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
c.pk_tbl_commodity, c.s_name, c.s_default_variant,
p.pk_tbl_parameter, p.s_name_parameter,
((SELECT SUM(p2.n_price_parameter) from tbl_Parameter p2
        WHERE p2.fk_tbl_commodity = p.fk_tbl_commodity 
        AND p2.b_default = 1 
        AND p2.s_name_parameter <> p.s_name_parameter GROUP BY NULL) + c.n_price_without_dph + p.n_price_parameter) as total 
FROM tbl_Commodity c JOIN tbl_Parameter p on (p.fk_tbl_commodity = c.pk_tbl_commodity) 
WHERE s_name like '%acti%' 
AND b_bin = '0'
AND total = 3340
ORDER BY s_name, s_default_variant;
```

I got the error:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'
```

How could I add condition on result of subquery and sum (column alias *total*)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases defined in the `SELECT` list cannot be referred in the `WHERE` list, simply because the (logical) order of execution of a query is `FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> (HAVING) -> SELECT`.

You can try replacing the `AND total = 3340` with `HAVING total = 3340` though.

This is not standard SQL but it is allowed in MySQL (which is flexible on the order of execution of the `HAVING` and `SELECT` clauses) and will save you from duplicating the code in the `WHERE` clause.

Another way would be to encapsualte the query in a derived table and pull the condition in the external `WHERE` clause.

So your options are:

- use `HAVING` (trick allowed in MySQL):

  ```
  SELECT 
    c.pk_tbl_commodity, c.s_name, c.s_default_variant,
    p.pk_tbl_parameter, p.s_name_parameter,
    (... long and complex subquery ...) AS total 
  FROM tbl_Commodity c JOIN tbl_Parameter p 
       on (p.fk_tbl_commodity = c.pk_tbl_commodity) 
  WHERE s_name like '%acti%' 
    AND b_bin = '0'
  HAVING total = 3340
  ORDER BY s_name, s_default_variant ;
  ```
- duplicate code in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses:

  ```
  SELECT 
    c.pk_tbl_commodity, c.s_name, c.s_default_variant,
    p.pk_tbl_parameter, p.s_name_parameter,
    (... long and complex subquery ...) AS total 
  FROM tbl_Commodity c JOIN tbl_Parameter p 
       on (p.fk_tbl_commodity = c.pk_tbl_commodity) 
  WHERE s_name like '%acti%' 
    AND b_bin = '0'
    AND (... long and complex subquery ...) = 3340
  ORDER BY s_name, s_default_variant ;
  ```
- encapsulate in a derived table:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM
    ( SELECT 
        c.pk_tbl_commodity, c.s_name, c.s_default_variant,
        p.pk_tbl_parameter, p.s_name_parameter,
        (... long and complex subquery ...) AS total 
      FROM tbl_Commodity c JOIN tbl_Parameter p 
           on (p.fk_tbl_commodity = c.pk_tbl_commodity) 
      WHERE s_name like '%acti%' 
        AND b_bin = '0'
    ) AS dt
  WHERE total = 3340
  ORDER BY s_name, s_default_variant ;
  ```

---

- since the `total` column will have a constant result (`3340`), you could also use (no duplication of code):

  ```
  SELECT 
    c.pk_tbl_commodity, c.s_name, c.s_default_variant,
    p.pk_tbl_parameter, p.s_name_parameter,
    3340 AS total 
  FROM tbl_Commodity c JOIN tbl_Parameter p 
       on (p.fk_tbl_commodity = c.pk_tbl_commodity) 
  WHERE s_name like '%acti%' 
    AND b_bin = '0'
    AND (... long and complex subquery ...) = 3340
  ORDER BY s_name, s_default_variant ;
  ```

(that would not work of course if the condition was `>= 3340` or anything else but equality.)